# Model comparsion for robust linear mixed models (robustlmm)

Tags: mixed-model, linear, aic, robust

I'm currently working on a project where I've fitted 4 robust linear mixed models. However, I've hit a bit of a roadblock when it comes to model selection. I've been using the AIC (Akaike Information Criterion) to compare models in the past, but I've realized that these particular models don't have log likelihood values that AIC relies on.

Given this constraint, I'm seeking advice on alternative methods for effectively comparing these robust linear mixed models. I want to make an informed choice between the two models, but the absence of log likelihood has made my usual approach unfeasible.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation or could suggest alternative techniques for model selection among robust linear mixed models?

Comment: If there is not a more efficient solution, maybe you can use cross-validation? This is what AIC tries to mimic anyways.

Comment: Do the models have different numbers of variables?   Are they nested?

Comment: Same random component (with random intercept) and different variables.